# PHP: change output of SQL Table before printout

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

i have a beginner Problem. I have following code to access a SQL Table but before i print it out (what works) i want to check if "Zustand" in the table is 0 or 1 and the function should change just the print out to f.e. 1 = good 0 = bad. Is this even possible or do i have to change my SQL Table?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Nr, Name, Zustand FROM Verbraucher";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Nr</th><th>Name</th><th>Zustand</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Nr"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Zustand"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query and use this one :

```
SELECT Nr, Name, IF(Zustand = 0, "bad", "good") AS Zustand FROM Verbraucher
```

Answer (score 0):

Relatively simple, just replace

```
. $row["Zustand"] .
```

with

```
. ($row["Zustand"] == 1 ? "good" : "bad") .
```

the notation with ? and : is a shorthand for an if / else statment

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible,

Inside the `while` loop, add an `if` block as below,

```
if($row["Zustand"]==1)
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Nr"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Name"]. "</td><td>" ."good". "</td></tr>";
else
  echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Nr"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Name"]. "</td><td>" . "bad". "</td></tr>";
```

Comment: thank you very much. :) Works perfect. For all the others which have trouble with it here the code: